# Create individual wallet for each user

Tags: bitcoin, wallet

I am going to develop an wallet service for bitcoin in Laravel , Now, I'm looking for resources and the best practice to start.
please guide me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, have you done any research?

Comment: Yes, but resources and working methods are too vague

Answer (score 0):

I would highly discourage writing your own PHP Wallet App, in which without proper security, your wallet and your clients wallets might be compromised in the future.

But if you insist on creating an online wallet, I would highly recommend Blockchain's Online Wallet.

You can access the source code [here](https://github.com/blockchain/unused-My-Wallet).

The application is written in Javascript, which enables the second layer of security (all operations are done on the user's browser). I think you can use this through your PHP application, in which nearly all web apps use Javascript libraries.

I would like you to go through [this](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/SSL_PHP_Server_Key_and_Certificate_generation).

[This](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=81626.20) is an example from Bitcointalk.

```
    < ? php
#Below is full list of available characters.

#"123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        $fp = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r") or die;
$available_chars = "23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz";
do
{
    $minikey = 'S';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 29; $i++)
    {
        while (($c = ord(fgetc($fp))) >= strlen($available_chars))
            ;
        $minikey.= substr($available_chars, $c, 1);
    }
    $check = hash('sha256', $minikey.'?')."\n";
} while (substr($check, 0, 2) != '00');
fclose($fp);

$priv = hash('sha256', $minikey);

print "Minikey: $minikey\n";

print "Privkey: $priv\n";
? >
```

More useful information [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro).